# execute bash script after successfully start systemd?

Tags: bash, daemon, systemd

I have `/etc/systemd/system/tivalue.service`  with following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Ti-Value Node
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/var/run/tivalue.pid

User=root
Group=root

ExecStart=/root/TiValue/tiValue --rpcuser=admin --rpcpassword=123456 --httpdendpoint=127.0.0.1:8080 --daemon
KillSignal=15
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and also `/etc/systemd/system/tivalue.curl.sh`

So, how can I execute `/etc/systemd/system/tivalue.curl.sh` after successfully started `tivalue.service`?

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site https://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 10):

Use an ExecStartPost= entry pointing at the script. See the [ExecStartPre/ExecStartPost documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=).

Comment: Dec 26 14:56:44 Ti-Value systemd[1]: tivalue.service: PID file /var/run/tivalue.pid not readable (yet?) after start-post: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you saying that you need the PID file in the script you want to run in ExecStartPost and it does not exist at that point?

Comment: If i delete ExecStartPost=/etc/systemd/system/tivalue.curl.sh
the everything works fine...

but with ExecStartPost=/etc/systemd/system/tivalue.curl.sh
doesnt work...

Comment: My curl scrypt is:

#!/bin/bash

curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: 000000YWhgh2" -X POST -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":2,"method":"55","params":["mox"]}' http://ip/tv


exit 0

so, what should I add?

Comment: The PIDFile should not be affected by the ExecStartPost. It isn't created by systemd but by the service itself, and the service startup should be unaffected. Is it possible that the script triggers something that causes the service to exit?

Comment: I deleted PIDFile=/var/run/tivalue.pid from my serivce and it seems like workining, is it correct?

Comment: I can't really tell since I don't know what that TiValue service is or does. Is it documented/configured to actually produce that PID file? And are you still able to stop and restart the service via systemd?

Comment: Yes i am still able

Comment: Then it sounds like everything's fine. The PIDFile is usually only used with forking services, i.e. ones where a daemon process is forked off to the background when the application starts. The PID file is then used to determine the PID of that forked off process so that systemd can monitor it. The service you showed in the question is declared as `Type=simple` so systemd expects the process it starts itself to be the main one. The PID file is then not really relevant.